# why not $G \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb {Z}} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}} ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Determine  the Galois  group   of $(x^2-2) (x^2-3)(x^2-5)$. Determine  all the subfields  of the splitting field  of this  polynomial.

My attempt: I found the answer  [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eajorza/courses/m5c-s2013/homeworksol/h05sol.pdf)

$G= Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ where$ K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt  5)$

It is written that

> $\sigma_2 \begin{cases}
> \sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}\\
> \sqrt{3}\mapsto \sqrt{3}\\
> \sqrt{5}\mapsto \sqrt{5}\\
> \end{cases}$

> $\sigma_3: \begin{cases}
> \sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2}\\
> \sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}\\
> \sqrt{5}\mapsto \sqrt{5}\\
> \end{cases}$

> $\sigma_5: \begin{cases}
> \sqrt{3}\mapsto \sqrt{3}\\
> \sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2}\\
> \sqrt{5}\mapsto -\sqrt{5}\\
> \end{cases}$

then obviously  $G= \langle \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_4 \rangle  \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}  \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$

**My question**:   why $G=\langle \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_4 \rangle  \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}  \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} ?$

Why not $\langle \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_5 \rangle  \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}}  \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb {Z}} \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}} ?$

**My  thinking**: $\sigma_2$ has $3$ choice  similarly $\sigma_3 $ and $\sigma_5$  have $3$ choice   so i think

$\langle \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_5 \rangle  \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}}  \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb {Z}} \times  \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{3\mathbb{Z}} $

Comment: Since quotients are built from left cosets, we write them as $$G/H$$ and not $\frac{G}{H}$.

Comment: @Shaun I don't think we ever really write it as $\frac GH$. Left, right or two-sided cosets have always been elements of $G/H$ that I've seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sigma_2$ doesn't have "three choices" it has 8:
$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto \sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto \sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto \sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto \sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto \sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto \sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto \sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto -\sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto \sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto -\sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto -\sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto -\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto -\sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Of course, to those of us in the know, only one of these deserve the name $\sigma_2$.

No, more important than the number of possibilities is its order. Choose
$$
\sigma_2:\begin{cases}
\sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{3}\mapsto \sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{5}\mapsto \sqrt{5}\\
\end{cases}$$
Then $\sigma_2^2$ is the identity. This means that $\langle \sigma_2\rangle\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Same for the other two $\sigma$'s. The way the three chosen $\sigma$'s interact (they commute, their generated subgroups intersect trivially, and together they generate the whole group) is what yields
$$
G=\langle \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_5 \rangle  \cong {\mathbb{Z}}/{2\mathbb{Z}}  \times  {\mathbb{Z}}/{2\mathbb{Z}} \times  {\mathbb{Z}}/{2\mathbb{Z}}
$$